# Why did the Separatists try to take Jango's DNA?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In the episode of The Clone Wars titled "ARC Troopers," the Separatists attack the Kamino cloning facilities in hopes of destroying them and having Ventress steal the host DNA for the clone troopers.  I understand the need to destroy the cloning facilities, but why would they need to take Jango Fett's DNA?  Couldn't the Kaminoans just use DNA from one of the existing clones?

Comment: See: [Multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(film)). A copy of a copy is never as good as a copy of the original. "Hey Steve, did ya bring me any pizza Steve?"

Comment: The DNA of the clones have been altered greatly. Having a sample of the original DNA makes sense.

Comment: Why would they want the original if they would just have to alter it again?  Wouldn't it make more sense to just clone the altered DNA?

Comment: Maybe because altering a copy of the original produces less defects than altering a copy of a copy.

Comment: The Clone Troopers are genetically bred to be loyal to the Republic. Something tells me the Separatists aren't going to want to create more clone troopers like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is dealt with in the [episode script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-wars-the-clone-wars&episode=s03e02);

- **The Kaminoans can't make copies of a copy**

> *"Ever since the unfortunate death of Jango Fett, we have had to stretch
>   his DNA to produce more clones."*

Clearly, having lost access to a primary source of his DNA, they're reliant on stocks of it. Stealing these would prevent them making more Jango clone troopers.

---

- **Possessing his DNA is helpful scientifically to the Seperatists** (not specified why, but I'm guessing [bio-weapons](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bioweapon) or researching any physical vulnerabilities)

> *"Why not just destroy it?"*
>
> *"Because the DNA could unlock new possibilities for us."*

Comment: Being able to create a virus that only killed clone-troopers would be pretty amazing for the Separatists.